# VBA - How to apply loop in this situation (Userform.Combox...)?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, vba

I tried "For i=1" etc... but not working, I just don't know the syntax.  Could you help me put this code into an "For i=1 to 33..."?

```
    ColorUpdateBoxes = RGB(255, 255, 180)
    With UserForm9
       .ComboBox1.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox2.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox3.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox4.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox5.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox6.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox7.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox8.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox9.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox10.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox11.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox12.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox13.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox14.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox15.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox16.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox17.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox18.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox19.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox20.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox21.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox22.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox23.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox24.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox25.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox26.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox27.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox28.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox29.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox30.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox31.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox32.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
       .ComboBox33.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `For Each` loop.

```
Dim c As Control

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
        c.BackColor = ColorUpdateBoxes
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Reddy - Wow, it works perfectly!!  You are a genius, what an efficient code!!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @SofiaEd I am no genius at all. When you code a little bit, you learn few tricks here and there.